# js callback после выполнения default функции

Tags: javascript

```
editor.on( 'fileUploadResponse', function( evt ) {
}
```

Я получаю callback(выше),  но мне нужно получить еще один  после завершения default действий для **fileUploadResponse** это возможно сделать?

ПС: **fileUploadResponse** вызывает сторонняя библиотека, поэтому какие либо действия можно производить только внутри **fileUploadResponse**

Comment: Ничего не понял, что значит "получаю callback"? В примере я вижу просто добавление обработчика события, на "получаю callback" это совсем не похоже

Comment: @andreymal , пусть так. Вопрос не изменился. Это событие вызывается когда файл загружен на сервер и пришел ответ, затем библиотека монтирует ответ в html.  Но это событие вызывается до монтировки, а мне нужно получить событие после.

Comment: Очевидно, обращайтесь к документации или разработчикам этой библиотеки, а не к нам. Или хотя бы саму библиотеку назовите

Comment: @andreymal. Вопрос имеет отношение к js, а не к библиотеке.  https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-fileUploadResponse

Comment: Порядок выполнения этих ваших callback'ов определяет именно библиотека. Когда там этот ваш html будет монтироваться, определяет именно библиотека — обычный js здесь абсолютно ни при чём.

Comment: @andreymal, это очевидно. В этом и вопрос можно ли средствами js в событии создать другое которое вывозится при завершении первого.

Comment: А зачем костылять средствами js, когда можно использовать родные средства ckeditor? Как я понял из его исходников, `evt.data.fileLoader.on('uploaded', function(){/* здесь нужный код */})` даст то, чего вы хотите. Я не проверял и мог соврать, но попробуйте

Comment: Если `uploaded` не то, то возможно `evt.data.fileLoader.on('update', function(){/* здесь нужный код */}, null, null, 1000)` возможно то. Вообще, без понимания конкретной задачи и без минимального работоспособного примера это всё гадание на кофейной гуще, и посоветовать что-то адекватное будет трудно

Comment: хм, я и не подумал изучить параметры.... 'update' можно в ответ(я потом откорректирую вопрос).